# how can add an icon within styled input element (styled component)?

Tags: reactjs, input, icons, styled-components

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGyMN.png)

Hey guys, i want to an icon to put inside of StyledInput component but input is not allowed a children. how can i fix that problem?

Comment: Hi Huseyin, could you please add the code to your question using code blocks, not an image? This helps your question be indexed properly in search engines, as well as making it easy for the community to have a look at your question and answer to you. 
See [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the Help section of Stack Overflow.
Also, please copy and paste the exact error message you are experiencing, rather than "input is not allowed a children".